# ERROR on lint:eslint when commit the code into local repositary

Tags: git

I have an error on `lint:eslint` which found some error as follows

```
Running tasks for *.js
 ✖ lint:eslint

   lint:eslint found some errors. Please fix them and try committing again.
```

So many errors happen in my updated js file when I commit the code.

I can't commit my code into my local repository. How can I elimianate this error? Can I need to make any changes needed in my `package.js`?

Answer (score 4):

Add `--no-verify` flag to commit:

e.g. `git commit --no-verify -m "Message"`

You have some problem with style of your code. Try to run checking code and fix them.

This `--no-verify` use as an hotfix or temporary solution :)

Answer (score 2):

> So many errors happen in my updated js file

Then fix those errors, and you'll be able to commit. Make sure your changes conform to the style guide configured for your linter.

Comment: how can i check that